# (block) size of /dev, /etc, /proc, /home, explanation?

Tags: linux, directory, size, fhs

Can somebody explain, why a standard folder has always 4kB and some special directories have more or less?

some examples:

- /dev   3280B, 0 Blocks, 16 Links
- /etc   12288B, 24 Blocks, 119 Links
- /proc  0B, 0 Blocks, 85 Links
- /home  4096B, 8 Blocks, 4 Links

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: `/dev` and `/proc` on Linux usually have special filesystems mounted on them (`devtmpfs`, `procfs`) so the mounted directories occupy zero space on disk.

Comment: @muru: got it, but why does /dev have a size of 3280B when it uses 0 blocks, and /proc have a size of 0B?

Comment: Probably some difference in implementation. Different decisions may have been taken about reporting (otherwise meaningless) stats about them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see proper size utilization of your directory/file in present directory please use below command :

du -sch *

for example :

```
[root:/]# du -sch *
0       bin
121M    boot
0       dev
22M     etc
20K     home
0       lib
0       lib64
0       media
0       mnt
316M    opt
0       proc
2.3M    root
25M     run
0       sbin
0       srv
0       sys
68K     tmp
1.1G    usr
269M    var
1.9G    total
```